# CakePHP: Remove "page:#" from url params

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, parameters, cakephp-2.3

I have a search form using the `get` method. The form works fine until I use it after paginating through the results.

Users can enter the site from any number of urls that look like `domain.com/serach/results/something/something_else/` the important part is the `domain.com/serach/results/`.

Here's what my code for the the form looks like:

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'type' => 'get',
    'url' => $this->Html->url(null, true),
));
```

This will make the form look like this:

```
<form action="http://domain.com/serach/results/something/something_else/" method="get">
```

The problem is that when I paginate the results it adds the page:2 or page:3 to the action so it looks like:

```
<form action="http://domain.com/serach/results/something/something_else/page:3" method="get">
```

Is there a built in function in CakePHP that lets me remove the `page:3`from the url that's being passed to the form action or am I going to have to create a function that looks for and removes the `page:#`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just set your url the verbose way:

```
'url' => array('controller' => 'x', 'action' => 'y') + $this->request->params['pass']
```

Done!

Comment: Doing it that wat doesn't work because it loses everything after the action. So it results in this `domain.com/serach/results/` rather than  this `domain.com/serach/results/something/something_else/`.